# Stabilizer $G_x$ of a $k$-valued point of an algebraic Stack

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks, group-actions, algebraic-stacks

An algebraic stack or Artin stack is a stack in
groupoids $\mathcal{X}$ over the étale site such that the diagonal
map of $\mathcal{X}$ is representable and there exists a smooth
surjection from (the stack associated to) a scheme to $\mathcal{X}$.

In [Wikipedia's article on stacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(mathematics)#Local_structure_of_algebraic_stacks) I found in the excerpt a statement on local structure of algebraic stacks I do not understand:

> […] Given a quasi-separated algebraic stack $\mathcal{X}$ locally of
> finite type over an algebraically closed field $k$ whose stabilizers are
> affine, and $x \in \mathcal{X} (k)$ a smooth and closed point
> with linearly reductive stabilizer group $G_x$, there exists an
> etale cover of the GIT quotient […].

My question is what is here the stabilizer $G_x$ of $x$ at all? Recall we did *not* assume that $\mathcal{X}$ is a quotient stack, therefore it seems to me not to make any sense to speak about a "stabilizer group" of $x \in \mathcal{X} (k)= \operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{Spec} k, \mathcal{X})$.

The point is that in order to talk about a
stabilizer group $G_x$ of $x$ it is necessary to require the existence of a group $G$ acting on the set $\mathcal{X} (k)$ of $k$-valued points.

But for general algebraic stacks there is no reason that there is no reason that such group $G$  acting on $\mathcal{X} (k) $ such that $G_x \subset G$, right? Could somebody help me to resolve my confusion?

Comment: You still have a groupoid action you're killing as every algstack is a groupoid quotient, and the automorphisms at a point of a groupoid still form a group. The stabilizers are still subgroups of automorphism groups as well.

Comment: I think I understand your argument. The (pre) stack $X$ is endowed with a fibred functor $F: X \to C$ to certain category $C$ and every fiber $F^{-1}(c)$ is a groupoid by definition. That means that for every $x \in F^{-1}(c)$ the set $Hom_{F^{-1}(c)}(x,x)$ equals $Aut(x)$. So for every $x \in X$ the group $Aut(x)$ acts on subset $\{f \in X(k) \ f(Spec(k)) =x \} \subset X(k)$ by composition $Spec(k) \to x \to x$. Is this the action you mean?

Comment: Something like that. Loop spaces are always groups, and the stabilizer is the based loop space at a point.  If you pull inertia back to a presentation, you literally get stabilizers wrt the smooth groupoid.

Comment: @Harry Gindi: What do you mean by a "loop space" in this context? I looked up for a formal definition of a stabilizer $G_x$ of a $1$-morphism $x: Spec(k) \to X$. By definition it is defined as  pullback (of stacks) of the morphisms $(x,x): Spec(k) \to X$ and the diagonal map $\Delta: X \to X \times_S X$. Also one can show that if $I_x$ is the inertia stack of $x: Spec(k) \to X$ then $G_x \cong I_x \times Spec(k)$.

Comment: What I not completely understand is why and how this $G_x$ can be identified as subgroup of group $Hom_{F^{-1}(c)}(x,x)= Aut_{F^{-1}(c)}(x)$. Do you know literature where this identification is proved or give sketch of the construction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was getting a little bit long for a comment, so I'll just write it here:

Let $X\simeq S//R$ be an algebraic stack presented by a smooth surjective map $S\to X$ with $S$ a scheme, then $R=S\times_X S$, and the pair of maps $R\rightrightarrows S$ has the canonical structure of a groupoid in algebraic spaces (with the additional structure coming from the higher simplices of the Cech nerve). Choosing a point $x$ in $X$ classified by some Zariski geometric point in $\operatorname{Spec}(k)\to S$, form the following big fibre square

$$
\begin{matrix}
G_x & \to & S\times_X \operatorname{Spec}(k)&\to& \operatorname{Spec}(k)\\
\downarrow&&\downarrow&&\downarrow\\
\operatorname{Spec}(k)\times_X S&\to& R &\to & S\\
\downarrow &&\downarrow&&\downarrow\\
\operatorname{Spec}(k)&\to&S&\to&X
\end{matrix}
$$

In this case, the maps $G_x\to S\times_X \operatorname{Spec}(k)$ and $S\times_X \operatorname{Spec}(k)$ are injective, being pullbacks of injective maps, which gives an injective map $G_x\to R$, including as the literal stabilizer of the point $x\in S$ by the 'action' of $R$, it is including as the subgroupoid of automorphisms fixing $x\in S$.

Comment: One point isn't completely clear to me. In your comment you wrote: "every algstack is a groupoid quotient." Could your give a reference where an algebraic stack is introduced / constructed in that way? Or that this construction is equivalent to that one from Stacks project: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/026N

Comment: As explaned in e.g. https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04TJ (here only for fppf) we can associate an alg stack to a smooth groupoid in algebraic spaces as groupoid quotient. But I not see why as you said every alg stack is obtained in that way.

Comment: @katalaveino By choosing a smooth cover by a scheme or algebraic space, you can regenerate a morita-equivalent groupoid by taking the Cech complex.  I don't know where this is in the stacks project, but it's easy to show that this always works.

Comment: If you happen to find when you stumble upon a literature source that explains this construction in detail, could you name it? So far I have searched without successful in Olson's Alg Stacks and Laumon's & Moret-Bailly's Champs algebrques.

Comment: @katalaveino It's more or less by the definition of an effective epimorphism, that is, a cover.

Comment: @katalaveino : see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04T3.

Comment: Sorry for digging out this topic again but recently 
I noticed an aspect in your answer I not understand.
You wrote that the pair $R\rightrightarrows S$ which has structure
of groupoid in alg spaces moreover has additional structure 
enconded in higher simplices of the Cech nerve. The last 
statement I not understand. Does this Cech nerve contain
a proper additional structure which cannot be derived intrinsically from
$R\rightrightarrows S$ if we forget the Cech nerve? 
If yes, which additional structure is encoded here by Cech nerve?

Comment: The reason that confuses me a bit is that generally if we start
with groupoid $R\rightrightarrows S$ (without this
additional sructure) we can always canonically 
associate to $R\rightrightarrows S$ a Cech nerve.
So seemingly this higher simplices of the Cech nerve
not contain additional information about 
$R\rightrightarrows S$, or do I miss an important point?

Comment: @katalaveino  The third term encodes associativity.  The term to look into is "coskeletal".  The Cech nerve of an internal groupoid is always 2-coskeletal.

Comment: That's interesting, up to now I thought that the main
role of a Cech nerve associated to a stack or it's corresponding 
groupoid was to provide neccessary  framework for building
 cohomology of this stack. About that it encodes 'associavity' 
in that context I haven't heard anything up to now.

Comment: Could you briefly explain which kind of 'associativity' 
the Cech nerve encodes here? Maybe you mean in the sense
that we implicitely consider the algebraic stack $X$ as a
$\infty$-category, and the data $R\rightrightarrows S$ resp it's
associated Cech nerve determines the weakened associativities
of $X$ in sense of the concept of equivalences of morphisms
in higher category theory? Or do you mean by 'encoded associativity' 
something else?

Comment: @katalaveino yes, I meant the first thing.

Comment: Now I'm a bit confused about considering (algebraic) stacks
as $\infty$-categories. Classically, stacks can be introduced
in two equivalent ways:
as a (usual) category $F$ fibered in groupoids over $(Sch)$
or as a sheaf in groupoids, ie a
contravariant $2$-functor.

How do you associate to an (alg) stack a structure of
$\infty$-categery concretely, which's weak associativity 
on higher morphisms is exactly
encoded in the Cech nerve of $R\rightrightarrows S$ as you said? Clearly, if we use the first description interpreting

Comment: a stack as an usual category, then (as every usual cat) 
it can be interpreted as $\infty$-category where all $k$-morphisms
for $k>1$ are strict identities. But I doubt that these are
exactly associativity equivalences encoded by Cech nerve 
since for usual categories these are trivial, here 
the Cech nerve is 'rich' in structure.
Could you explain or give a source where the (alg) 
stacks are introduced as higher categoretical object
such that it contains nontrivial associative equivalences
encoded exactly by this coskeletal structure of Cech nerve?

Comment: @katalaveino It's the geometric realization of an internal Kan complex (in the category of (higher) fppf sheaves on Aff).  The higher structure in the  Cech nerve is not rich, it is coskeletal.  You can see this from the fact that the diagonal of an algebraic stack is a relative algebraic space. I suggest looking through Jon Pridham's paper on simplicial schemes and algebraic stacks if you're still confused.